# Get/Read files from SharePoint document library and ZIP them using DotNetZip?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dotnetzip

I have files uploaded to sharepoint document library. Trying to use DotNetZip to get those files from document library, zip them and render the zip file.

```
    Response.Clear();       
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + "MyFiles.zip");

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())

    {
    //Query the sharepoint document library and get SPFolder (folder in this case)

      foreach (SPFolder folder in userFolder.SubFolders)
      {
        foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)

        {

                zip.AddFile(file.URL);// Is this possible?
        }    
      }       
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

Can we pass file URL to AddFile method? If not, is there any another way to do this?

Comment: I got it. Looks like we need to use ZipOutputStream class for this.

Answer (score 0):

The dotnetzip addfile method does not accept urls. It needs to be a relative or full qualified path. See [the documentation](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/html/b1d9ff87-214d-d219-af0c-8075512cb3a9.htm)

Comment: I got it working. Looks like we have to use ZipOutputStream class for what I was trying to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [vZIP](http://www.vialutions.com/products/sharepoint-add-ons/vzip/) add-on, it is working great on our SharePoint 2010.